# Neo4j conditional batch import

Tags: neo4j, batch-processing

The data comes to the system continuosly with rate 300-500 TPS. I need to import it to neo4j with the following scheme:

1. If N node does not exist, create it
2. If the relation N-[rel:rel_type]->X does not exist, create it
3. Increment rel.weight

It seems to be impossible to solve the problem using REST batch.
Different cypher queries are too long because they generate many small transactions.

Gremlin works much faster. I collect parameters for gremlin script in array and execute it as a batch. But even though I could hardly reach the speed of 300 TPS.

I should mention that besides there will be a flow of queries ~500 TPS:

```
START N=node(...) MATCH N-[rel:rel_type]->X return rel.weight,X.name;
```

The heap size is set to 5 Gb. Additional options:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1G -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseNUMA
```

What is optimal way and configuration for importing such kind of data?

Comment: Have you tried using the REST batch insertion without using cypher or gremlin ? The batch is running on a single transaction, and I got pretty decent performance (especially if the process that is doing the insertion is on the same box as the db)

Answer (score 3):

to check whether or not the incoming node exists and has the  rels to other node, you can use create unique syntax.

```
START n=node:node_index(newNode={N})
CREATE UNIQUE n-[:REL_TYPE]->x ;
```

to automatically increment the weight of the relationship, i would assume something like this (but no warranty on this, there is probably a faster way of doing it):

```
START n=node:node_index(newNode={N})
CREATE UNIQUE n-[rel:REL_TYPE]->x
SET rel.weight = coalesce(rel.weight?,0) +1
```

Comment: The problem is that REST API accepts only one Cypher request in a query/transaction. This method cannot guarantee me the speed needed.

Comment: yes, above are 2 different queries. it was not meant to use them both at once. the second query does contain the first as well (although i haven't checked it so it might popup some syntax error).

Comment: That's not true, the Batch-REST-API accepts as many cypher statements as you want. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-batch-ops.html I had pretty decent performance with that. Make sure to use parameters.

Comment: Yes, I have put all my cypher requests to a single batch statement, but after that neo4j was not able to response any other queries in time. The load was too high.